# How can I bind data to dropdown on every postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Asp.Net MVC, getting data from db and binding into the dropdown. On postback of the page, dropdown items becomes empty. Every postback need to hit the db and bind the dropdown ?
Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide some code where the problem actually accures?

Answer (score 0):

Web requests (regardless of its technology, MVC, Webforms, etc.) are stateless. So, everytime a new request (of a "full postback" as you call it) occures, you've lost the state of the previous request.

So, **yes**, you need to reload the data from the database and rebind the Dropdown, but without your code, it's hard to tell you how and when to do it. However, a number of thing can be done to prevent a database hit. Choose what suits your need:

- [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to refresh only some part of the web page you need;
- [Memory caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) on the server (using a [cache service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) or output caching even);
- [Using sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (not recommended);